# How to concatenate a string at the end of another string after using getch

Tags: c++, string, getch, conio

For this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    char c{};
    while (c != '\r')
    {
        c = getch();
        a += c;
    }
    a += "xyz";
    std::cout << a;
}
```

---

> Input: `12345`, then <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> key

---

> Output: `xyz45`

---

How do I stop this from happening?

---

> Desired output: `12345xyz`

---

Comment: Think about what happens once `c=getch()` returns a `'\r'` character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to avoid adding `\r` character to the string, something like:

```
while ((c = getch()) != '\r')
    a += c;
```